# Python text to speech (pyttsx3) delay when i use it with tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

i am trying to learn about GUI and i thought of making a simple chat bot as a project, and it could also speak( using pyttsx3 library)... but when it speaks, it speaks first then it stops, then is labels it out in the GUI window. in conclusion... it lags with a slight delay... here is the code

```
import random
import tkinter as tk
import pyttsx3
engine = pyttsx3.init()

def speak(ui):
    engine.say(ui)
    engine.runAndWait()
    engine.stop()

root = tk.Tk()
user_input = tk.Entry(root)
user_input.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
root.geometry("200x200")
greetings = ['hola', 'hello', 'hi', 'Hi', 'hey!', 'hey']
question = ['How are you?', 'How are you doing?']
responses = ['Okay', "I'm fine"]
huh = "I did not understand what you said"

def cb():
    user_text = user_input.get()
    if user_text in greetings:
        bot_text = random.choice(greetings)
        speak(bot_text)
    elif user_text in question:
        bot_text = random.choice(responses)
        speak(bot_text)
    else:
        bot_text = huh
    output.config(text=bot_text)

button = tk.Button(root, text="Enter", command=cb)
button.grid(row = 0)

output = tk.Label(root, text='')
output.grid()

tk.mainloop()
```

are there any ways to fix this issue? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I am relitivly new to this concept, but I think what you're looking for is multithreading. By opening the GUI and bot on two seperate threads, they can run at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread, but maybe can be useful to someone: do not use threading with this simple task, you'll make the process uselessly heavy, just use the Lambda with your command in button like:

```
button = tk.Button(root, text="Enter", command=lambda: cb())
```